# luatex and using both English and Arabic bibliography with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, luatex, natbib, arabic

I am using `luatex` with the following example:

```
\documentclass[article, 11pt, b6paper, landscape, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage[nopar]{quran}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
```

This is to cite an English reference which is \cite{Abumostafa1993HintsVC}; and this is to cite the Arabic reference which is \txarb{\cite{MyKey}}. As you see, the Arabic in-text citation is messed up and the bibliography section cannot catch the bib info.

```
\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{asa}
\bibliography{tmp}

\end{document}
```

[image: in-text citation] [image: Bibliography]

My bib file is:

```
@Article{Abumostafa1993HintsVC,
  author =   {Abumostafa, Y S},
  title =    {{Hints and the Vc Dimension}},
  journal =  {Neural Computation},
  year =     1993,
  volume =   5,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {278-288},
  isbn =     {0899-7667}
}

@Article{MyKey,
  author =   {المؤلف},
  title =    {العنوان},
  journal =  {المجلة},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   5,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {278-288},
  isbn =     {0899-7667}
}
```

I have never been successful in to produce a good pdf in the case that my `bib` file has both English and Arabic `bib` items.

I am using emacs and auctex, which uses by default bibtex. I have Archlinux and use texlive.

EDIT:
After trying using biblatex and biber (per the advice of the comments below):

```
    \documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{tmp.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{Abumostafa1993HintsVC}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{MyKey}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

this is the result (not appropriate of course):
[image]

EDIT:
When I ran biber from the shell, it gave me this error messages:

```
[0] Config.pm:302> INFO - This is Biber 2.9
[0] Config.pm:305> INFO - Logfile is 'tmp.tex.blg'
[49] biber:313> INFO - === Wed Dec 13, 2017, 12:44:00
[127] Utils.pm:185> ERROR - Cannot find control file 'tmp.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
[127] Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

EDIT:
I tried after adding the `fontspec` and `arabluatex` and compiling with emacs after clean all. The code is:

```
\documentclass[article, 11pt, b6paper, landscape, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage[nopar]{quran}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    url=false,
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tmp.bib}

\begin{document}
This is to cite an English reference which is \cite{Abumostafa1993HintsVC}; and this is to cite the Arabic reference which is \cite{MyKey}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

However, it compiled and generated the pdf but without the Arabic name of the author in both the in-text citation and bibliography. The output is:
[image] [image]

Comment: Please tell us how you run BibTeX. Do you run the "basic" (7-bit) version of bibtex, `bibtex8` (which can handle 8-bit-encoded input), or (better still) `bibtexu`, which can handle utf8-encoded input natively? For that matter, which TeX distribution do you employ? It would be helpful if you edited your posting to provide a couple of examples of both english and arabic bib entries.

Comment: One more thing: Is the `asa` bibliography style online somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure; but if you suggest another style to use and produce the output that is fine. Edit: I have just tried IEEEtran and removed the `natbib` package; same problem exists!

Comment: From emacs, do `Command -> Clean all`. Then recompile with lualatex, then do biber once, and finally recompile with lualatex twice.

Comment: I have done that exactly; `biber` generated the bib without the Arabic names. Please, see the EDIT above at the end of the post.

Comment: `arabluatex` uses Amiri font by default. What do you get from `fc-list | grep -i amiri`?

Comment: I ran it from emacs; I got:
`/usr/share/fonts/TTF/amiri-quran.ttf: Amiri Quran:style=Regular,عادي
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/amiri-bold.ttf: Amiri:style=Bold,عريض
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/amiri-regular.ttf: Amiri:style=Regular,عادي
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/amiri-slanted.ttf: Amiri:style=Slanted,مائل
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/amiri-quran-colored.ttf: Amiri Quran Colored:style=Regular,عادي
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/amiri-boldslanted.ttf: Amiri:style=Bold Slanted,عريض مائل`

Comment: So you have Amiri. Could you check your tmp.bib file just to make sure that to didn't forget to put all the Arabic into `\txarb{}` just as I did in my answer below?

Comment: Oh; I removed it because I understood from you that `biber` and `biblatex` will not need it! Now, (1) after I put `\txarb{}`in `tmp.bib` it produced exactly as your pdf below. But now: what is the difference then as long as I put `\txarb{}` in the `bib` file. (2) still the Arabic bibliography is LR not RL

Comment: No, `biblatex+biber` are needed anyway, but you won't have any Arabic printed if not inside `\txarb{}`. As for the RTL bibliography, as I said, in this comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405638/luatex-and-using-both-english-and-arabic-bibliography-with-natbib#comment1012102_405905 you may have to teach `biblatex` how the fields are to be displayed. I think that kind of work hasn't been done so far.

Comment: I managed to solve all of that; thanks so much. I will open a new question for the only two remaining issues, since the main thing is solved here. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly advice to use `biblatex` and `biber` instead of `natbib` and `bibtex`.  That said, with `arabluatex` `\txarb{}` is only to be used with unicode Arabic script as its argument: this is why `\txarb{\cite{somekey}}` cannot work.  Instead, you have to put `\txarb{}` in your .bib file at the appropriate places, like so:

```
@Article{Abumostafa1993HintsVC,
  author =   {Abumostafa, Y S},
  title =    {{Hints and the Vc Dimension}},
  journal =  {Neural Computation},
  year =     1993,
  volume =   5,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {278-288},
  isbn =     {0899-7667}
}

@Article{MyKey,
  author =   {\txarb{المؤلف}},
  title =    {\txarb{العنوان}},
  journal =  {\txarb{المجلة}},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   5,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {278-288},
  isbn =     {0899-7667}
}
```

As to your .tex file:

```
\documentclass[article, 11pt, b6paper, landscape, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage[nopar]{quran}
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tmp.bib}

\begin{document}

This is to cite an English reference which is
\textcite{Abumostafa1993HintsVC}; and this is to cite the Arabic
reference which is \textcite{MyKey}. As you see, the Arabic in-text
citation is messed up and the bibliography section cannot catch the
bib info.

\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which gives this result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much; is there any way to have that particular reference in right-left style?

Comment: There is, by teaching `biblatex` how the fields are to be displayed in Arabic references.  For instance, such strings as the parentheses, 'In', 'pp.' and the like must be translated or adapted so that they are not printed RTL. Then, when you have achieved that, I would advise to have all of your Arabic references printed in a separate list. More details on how to get started: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/293935/72582 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297505 (but mind to get rid of all the polyglossia thing if you want to work with `arabluatex`)

Comment: Thanks so much; I will read all of that. I tried biblatex and biber for the simple example above. I was not successful as well. I will update the post to reflect the output.

Comment: You just forgot to load `arabluatex` in your mwe!

Comment: Sorry; I added it right below the the `class`. Same problem. However, I found that `biber` is not installed; so I installed it. Same problem as well.!

Comment: Everything compiles fine on my side with your exact mwe plus the `\usepackage{arabluatex}` line.  I suspect something may be wrongly installed or missing on your side.