# How do I add a language field (label) in JabRef?

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

I'm using JabRef and I want to add a field for the language.
Do you have any idea how to do it?

**Edit:**
I'm trying to make a bibliography with English and Hebrew references, and I want to make a field for *any* reference that I can write the language of it...

Actually I'm trying to what I asking here: [I do I divide the bibliography in LyX for Hebrew and English?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445741/i-do-i-divide-the-bibliography-in-lyx-for-hebrew-and-english)
but all the answers I found put a label  of language. So I was wondering how to do it via JabRef (and not manually at the file itself).

Comment: What is the language? Could you be more detailed, please, in your question?

Comment: Could you please specify which type of entry you are aiming at?

Comment: I edited my question :) @Sebastiano

Comment: @TeXnician I hope it's much clear now...

Comment: From what I recall, JabRef allows you to put custom information in the bibliography entries. The issue is that your bibliography style won't load them. JabRef is not responsible for what appears on the document. It just make editing the bibliography database easier. What appears on the doc is up to `bibtex` or `biblatex` and your bibliography style in use.

Comment: @phollox, thank you! But how I'm doing it?

Comment: @heblyx check this link, specially the part of custom bibliography. It refers to `makebst` which allows you to create a custom style. On the other hand, you could probably put the language in the "note" field of JabRef and your current bibliography style might actually call it and show it.

Comment: @phollox which link?

Comment: Sorry. Typing from cellphone and forgot to paste it. This link https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management It is pretty basic information about the way the whole bibliography system works. I know you use LyX so most of these concepts also apply there. Check that your document is linking to a `.bib` file. Check your style. See if you need `natbib`. Try using the note field on the `.bib` file (the one edited with JabRef) to put the language. And if that doesn't work try to create a custom style using `makebst`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use BibLaTeX (File > Database properties), the built-in entry types have a `language` field. For BibTeX you can edit the entry types yourself under Options > Customize entry types and add the language field (see also the [JabRef help about this topic](http://help.jabref.org/en/CustomEntryTypes)).