# How to make Hebrew bibliographic entries right-aligned and English bibliographic entries left-aligned?

Tags: biblatex, horizontal-alignment, babel, hebrew, right-to-left

The following BibTeX document is saved in `~/TestBib.bib`.

```
@book{silberstein,
   author = {Shel Silverstein},
   title = {The Giving Tree},
   year = {1964},
   langid = {english}
}
@book{goldberg,
   author = {Lea Goldberg},
   title = {An Apartment for Rent},
   year = {1959},
   langid = {hebrew}
}
```

The following LaTeX document is saved in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
%\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}    
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{TestBib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{silberstein}\cite{goldberg}    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed in the Terminal:

> > cd ~
> > lualatex Test
> > biber Test
> > lualatex Test

the file `~/Test.pdf` is generated. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows.

[image: An English document with a bibliography]

If now the two commented lines are uncommented, and the `.tex` file is recompiled as above, the resulting `.pdf` file displays as follows.

[image: A Hebrew document with a bibliography]

(Note that Hebrew is a right-to-left language.)

Is it possible to set things up in such a way that bibliographic entries whose `langid` field is Hebrew would be right aligned with right-to-left text flow, whereas bibliographic entries whose `langid` field is English would be left aligned with left-to-right text flow?

For comparison, a similar effect to what I'm after can be accomplished easily using the `bidi` package (which requires the `xelatex` compiler) as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem LLea Goldberg. \emph{An Apartment for Rent}. 1959
\begin{LTRbibitems}
\bibitem SShel Silverstein. \emph{The Giving Tree}. 1964
\end{LTRbibitems}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: A correctly formatted bidirectional bibliography using the bidi package]

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/293935/21685) is a similar question to mine, but the answer given there uses two separate bibliographies, whereas I'm interested in one continuous bibliography.

P.S.

It can be assumed that those bibliographic entries with `langid` equal to `hebrew` are in Hebrew, and not in English as in the example above. I'm not looking to recreate the right-to-left text flow effect on *English* text as in the `bidi`+`xelatex` example above.

---

I have added [an enhancement request](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1252) to the `biblatex` bug tracking so that the issue described in this post can be dealt with easily, flexibly, and naturally by `biblatex`.

Comment: I’ve posted an answer to the enhancement request: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1252#issuecomment-1328006393 .

Comment: @JavierBezos Great. Thanks! Incidentally, you may want to check out [this other bug report](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1254), which I've opened in the `biblatex` bug tracker. It may be a bug in `babel` rather than in `biblatex`, I'm not sure. I discovered this bug by observing the output of Cicada's code in [their answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666491/21685), and noticing that it was not as I'd expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While waiting for the enhancement, since LuaTex inherit's Omega's directionality commands, a  potential workaround could be to use `luabidi` package's `\setLTR` command at every bibitem to reverse the item's paragraph direction for, say, non-hebrew `langid`s (to relocate the bibitem label), and then insert a small amount of horizontal space.

[image: example]

I took the liberty of applying a negative fake slant for the titles in the Hebrew font.

Default Bibsorting for numeric style appears to be Unicode-based, by family name of first author.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@Book{מישהו1990,
  title     = {ספר},
  publisher = {הוצאה},
  date      = {1990},
  author    = {מישהו},
  langid    = {hebrew}
}
@Book{lg,
  title     = {דירה להשכיר},
%  publisher = {xxx},
  date      = {1959},
  author    = { לאה גולדבר},
  langid    = {hebrew}
}


@book{silberstein,
   author = {Shel Silverstein},
   title = {The Giving Tree},
   year = {1964},
   langid = {english}
}
@book{goldberg,
   author = {Lea Goldberg},
   title = {An Apartment for Rent},
   year = {1959},
   langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luabidi}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,english,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}    
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Colour=blue,AutoFakeSlant=-0.2]{FreeSans}    

\usepackage[autolang=other*]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%\AtEveryBibitem{\currentlang :: \thefield{langid}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldequalstr{langid}{hebrew}{}{\setLTR\hspace{\leftmargin}\hspace{\itemsep}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{silberstein} \cite{lg} \cite{goldberg}    \cite{מישהו1990}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or wrap the LTR items with `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}` — `\end{otherlanguage}`.

Comment: @JavierBezos Maybe you can provide a separate answer. Your opinion is highly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I've pruned down [Cicada's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666491/21685) so that the essential parts are readily apparent.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{silverstein,
   author = {Shel Silverstein},
   title = {The Giving Tree},
   year = {1964},
   langid = {english}
}
@Book{goldberg,
   author = {לאה גולדברג},
   title = {דירה להשכיר},
   year = {1959},
   langid = {hebrew}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{english}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
   \savefield{langid}{\langid}%
   \selectlanguage{\langid}%
   \iffieldequalstr{langid}{hebrew}%
   {}%
   {%
      \hspace{\leftmargin}%
      \hspace{\biblabelsep}%
   }%
}
\begin{document}
\cite{silverstein}\cite{goldberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If the above code is saved in `~/Test.tex`, and the following commands are then executed in the Terminal:

```
\> cd ~
\> lualatex Test
\> biber Test
\> lualatex Test
```

then the file `~/Test.pdf` is generated. When opened in a PDF viewer, it displays as follows. (Only the relevant part of the display was captured in the screenshot.)

[image: A bidirectional bibliography]